# Running Powershell in C# and Powershell is behaving differently

Tags: c#, powershell

The image shows the same powershell command executed in a C# and Powershell ISE. My question is, Powershell shows complete list of process and process directory, but the result of the code executed in C# does not contain windows processes like svchost.exe.

Of course, both my C# Form and Powershell ISE are running as Administrator.
Also, I made sure to code my form to launch with administrative privileges.
To be double sure, I executed my C# by right click - Run as Administrator (what I also did with Powershell ISE)

Command/s: Powershell and C#

```bsh
get-process | get-item -erroraction silentlycontinue | format-table name, directory

get-process | format-table name, directory
```

Although this particular command shows all the process:

```bsh
get-process
```

Unfortunately, combining it with the syntax above will show different output from C#.

```
private string RunScript(string script)
{

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    runspace.Close();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    output.Clear();
    output.Text = RunFilePs1(input.Text);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you'd find out why if you removed `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` (don't forget to inspect `pipeline.Error` after execution) :)

Comment: I played with the command but the output is the same. -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -This syntax only catch errors and does nothing with the code:(

Comment: Psychic debugging: your ISE is running as Administrator, your program is not.

Comment: Your ISE says it's running as administrator. Your C# process probably isn't. It will see different things

Comment: My application is also running as administrator :)

Comment: can you post your powershell script as well?

Comment: Yes, I included the script after editing.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Get-Process doesn't return the Path of some processes (probably the 64-bit ones) when running in 32-bit mode, so passing those to Get-Item fails to find anything.

You can see this by running your PS script from the x86 PS ISE.

[image]

So if you switch your C# Form to 64-bit, it will return all processes.